# Run a script when Infinite-scroll is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the script here is [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) which is a emoji library from twitter that I am using on my [blog](http://vizzxd.tumblr.com/).

Here's the manual Trigger code that i'm using:

```
var $container = $('.content');
$container.infinitescroll({
    //[your options here],
    errorCallback: function(){
        $('.load-more').hide();
    }
});
$(window).unbind('.infscr');
$('.load-more').click(function(){
    $container.infinitescroll('retrieve');
    return false
});
```

See this [tutorial](http://shythemes.tumblr.com/post/142121772833/tutorial-load-more-buttons) for help.

I am using manual-Load / [infinite-scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) on my [blog](http://vizzxd.tumblr.com/) and when the manual trigger is initiated I want the Twemoji script to run along.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you just put anything else you wanted to run after `$container.infinitescroll('retrieve');`?

Answer (score 0):

As said in "All options" parts of [infinite sroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) plugin,

you have a callback after new content is loaded.

Code is like this:

```
   $('#content').infinitescroll({}, function(arrayOfNewElems){

     // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.

     // here you can call Twemoji plugin on new content
});
```